# What is difference between Tableau and QlikView

Tags: tableau-api, qlikview

Recently I learned Tableau Visualization tool but I am not able differentiate between Tableau and QlikView.
could any one detailed me what's functional difference, I take round in google so please don't reply copy past from google.

Answer (score 5):

Not a detailed functional difference analysis, no, but an overview as I see it.

Tableau is, as you say, a visualisation tool - it has some fairly simple data loading capabilities, but for complex environments relies on other data extraction tools like Alteryx. Tableau focuses on the front-end with things like a wide range of chart types, recommended chart types based on the nature of the data. That said, it is not a fully-responsive web-based product - you design separately for mobile and other different screen resolutions.

QlikView it's fair to say isn't as "pretty" as Tableau, but it does have a very powerful data extraction script language as well as in-memory associative technology for very fast data analysis. It's also not fully-responsive in a web browser - although it does have some limited mobile functionality that works out of the box.

You should also look at Qlik Sense (essentially the successor to QlikView) which seems to me to be the best of both worlds - it's visually appealing like Tableau but has the powerful ETL tools and in-memory technology of QlikView.

Hope that helps. I think the Gartner BI 2017 report just came out, so it'd be worth looking at that for a broader overview of capabilities across BI tools.